# sql duplicated query results

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have table like below:

```
Table: port 
tid    leftside    rightside 
1      2           3          
2      3           2
3      2           4
4      4           2
5      4           3
6      3           4
7      4           5
8      5           4
9      3           6
10     6           3
```

When I run this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM port pt JOIN port p 
  ON (pt.leftside = p.rightside 
     and p.leftside <> 2) 
WHERE pt.rightside = 2
```

I got this result

```
tid    leftside    rightside 
6      3           4 
5      4           3
8      5           4
10     6           3
```

The first two lines represents same relation altough they are located opposite sides.
I want my query to retrieve only one line if there are duplicated records.
For example: 
The query should return below line

```
tid    leftside    rightside 
6      3           4
```

instead of

```
tid    leftside    rightside 
6      3           4 
5      4           3
```

these lines.

Answer (score 0):

I played with it in MS SQL

```
with port as
(
select 1 as tid, 2 as leftside, 3 as rightside
UNION ALL
select 2, 3, 2
UNION ALL
select 3, 2, 4
UNION ALL
select 4, 4, 2
UNION ALL
select 5, 4, 3
UNION ALL
select 6, 3, 4
UNION ALL
select 7, 4, 5
UNION ALL
select 8, 5, 4
UNION ALL
select 9, 3, 6
UNION ALL
select 10, 6, 3
)
SELECT * 
FROM port pt JOIN port p 
  ON (pt.leftside = p.rightside 
     and p.leftside <> 2) 
WHERE pt.rightside = 2
```

and got these results -

```
(pt.tid pt.leftside pt.rightside p.tid p.leftside p.rightside)
2   3   2   5   4   3
4   4   2   6   3   4
4   4   2   8   5   4
2   3   2   10  6   3
```

By adding an `in (subquery)` to the WHERE clause ...

```
SELECT *
FROM port pt JOIN port p 
  ON (pt.leftside = p.rightside 
    and p.leftside <> 2) 
WHERE (pt.rightside = 2)
   AND p.tid in (SELECT max(chk.tid) FROM port chk
                 GROUP BY Case when leftside>rightside
                             then rightside else leftside end,
                          Case when leftside<rightside
                             then rightside else leftside end
                )
```

it gets rid of the row where p.tid=5, because it's not the higher (Max) value of the matching pair.

Explanation : this lists all 10 rows, with left and right sides in lower/higher order.

```
SELECT tid,
  Case when leftside>rightside then rightside else leftside end as lower,
  Case when leftside<rightside then rightside else leftside end as higher
FROM port
```

So, by GROUPing on lower&higher, and retrieving the max(tid), we get the higher tid of matching pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to swap over `leftside` and `rightside` whenever `leftside` is larger than `rightside`. Then use `PARTITION BY` and `RANK` to cut out the duplicates:

```
SELECT tid,
       leftside,
       rightside
FROM
(
  SELECT p.tid,
         CASE WHEN p.leftside <= p.rightside
              THEN p.leftside
              ELSE p.rightside
         END AS leftside,
         CASE WHEN p.leftside > p.rightside
              THEN p.leftside
              ELSE p.rightside
         END AS rightside,
         RANK() OVER
         (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN p.leftside <= p.rightside
                            THEN p.leftside
                            ELSE p.rightside
                       END,
                       CASE WHEN p.leftside > p.rightside
                            THEN p.leftside
                            ELSE p.rightside
                       END
          ORDER BY p.tid ASC) AS rank
  FROM port pt JOIN port p 
    ON (pt.leftside = p.rightside
        AND p.leftside <> 2)
  WHERE pt.rightside = 2  
) subquery
WHERE rank = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf1dc/23)

Comment: `pt.leftside < p.rightside` gives 0 rows, `pt.leftside <= p.rightside` gives all 4 rows still :)  `AND p.leftside > p.rightside` gives 3 rows, but with tid 5 instead of tid 6

Comment: pt.lefts are all > pt.rights - you can have 0 rows or all 4 if you reverse the test :)

Comment: You're right - edited my answer to use a different method and tested it this time!